# Laravel 5 Displaying image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display an image stored in /resources/assets/img/champions/

with

```
     <img class="img-rounded"
           src="{{asset("/resources/assets/img/champions/Ahri.png")}}"
                style="width:32px;height:32px;">
```

Which gives me this output

```
<img class="img-rounded" 
src="http://localhost:8000/resources/assets/img/champions/Ahri.png" style="width:32px;height:32px;">
```

from what i know this should display the image right?

going to the path in the browser so

```
http://localhost:8000/resources/assets/img/champions/Ahri.png
```

gives me

```
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8140:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Laravel 5 `resources` folder is **not** web accessible.

The `asset()` helper's URLs start from the `public` directory. Move `resources/assets/img/champions/Ahri.png` to `public/resources/assets/img/champions/Ahri.png` (or anywhere else in `public`) and it'll work.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Hi, I've image in `public/uploads/admin/profileImage/hairstyle.jpg` and it's not displaying when i'm trying `<img src="{{ asset($getAdminUser->profile_pic) }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">` and also in my web URL `http://localhost:8000/public/uploads/admin/profileImage/hairstyle.jpg`. Im saving full path in db like: `public/uploads/admin/profileImage/hairstyle.jpg` and then use `asset()` to display it! Any idea??

Comment: I've fixed! I only need to save `/uploads/....` not like `public/uploads/...` and then i use `{{ URL::to($var->image)}}` and it works!